# How to put span content on top of all other elements without wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have a span next to each form element on a page that shows an error if there is one. There are basically two columns on the page, a left and a right. I'm trying to get the span to display from the left column all the way across the page (not getting wrapped to a 2nd line at the boundries of the left column).

I've been playing around with positioning and z-indexes for a while and can't get it working, so I thought I'd post a jsfiddle to see if someone could help shed some light:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZ7MN/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.one_third, .two_third {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

.formerror {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 320px;
    top: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #FF7878;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    color: #D8000C;
}
```

Comment: But how reusable is this? If there are multiple errors on the page, wouldn't they just stack on top of each other? **EDIT** I tested it with fiddle, and the error still wrapped!

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: it won't be wrapped if you extend the width of the "Result" fiddle area

Comment: Ah, right you are... But it *does* stack the error messages on top of each other: http://jsfiddle.net/zZ7MN/5/

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: it is reusable if you set own "top" and "left" properties for each error message. Anyway this is a hack to the existing problem. If I would have to create such error message - I would make it on top of the input box, with smaller font, so it would fit without wrapping and no "absolute" styling would be needed ;)

Comment: This doesn't work due to the #content margin being **margin: 15px auto; **. I was trying to get the .formerror to display 20px to the right of the form element (see example posted above)

Comment: @Dmitriy I agree. Trying to make it work across floated divs as well as inside tables is pretty crazy.

Comment: ...as far as stacking the error messages, each span will be in a table TD.

Answer (score 0):

```
.formerror {
    position: absolute;
    width: 560px;
    overflow: visible;        
    border: 1px solid #FF7878;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    color: #D8000C;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Dmitriy was close, his problem was that he was specifying a left attribute. When the position is changed to absolute this causes the span to move N amount of pixels from the left of the screen. Remove the left and give your span a set width and it will no longer wrap!!

Here is the solution in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zZ7MN/8/